# sql multiple conditions together not true

Tags: sql

My question is very simple but I cannot get my head around

my statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 1 
WHERE (row1 = 0 AND row2 > 0) 
   OR (row3 is NULL AND row4 > 0)
```

This gives me a selection of rows that is correct for one option.

What I want is making a selection of all rows where the where clause is not true in total

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table 1
WHERE NOT((row1 = 0 AND row2 > 0) 
           OR (row3 is NULL AND row4 > 0))
```

what is wrong is

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 1 
WHERE (row1 > 0 AND row2 = 0) 
   OR (row3 is NOT NULL AND row4 = 0)
```

Comment: Example data and expected output please.

Comment: you are realy cryptic

Comment: Sorry if I am cryptic basically I want all rows from my table except for the (row1 = 0 and row2 > 0) or  (row3 is null and row4 > 0) condition

Comment: Can row1, row2, or row4 be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for? I've assumed you meant fields rather than rows though...

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE not exists

(select *
from table1
 where
 ((field1 = 0 and field2 > 0) OR (field3 IS NULL AND field4 > 0)))
```

Maybe see this for further information on NOT IN AND NOT EXISTS to exclude results based on your subquery specification:

[NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: This is what I  was looking for, thank SelectDistinct

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is to do with `NULL` values in columns, because any predicate with NULL evaluates to NULL, so is neither true or false:

Imagine a simple table `T` with one column (Col):

```
Col
-----
1
2
3
NULL
```

So if we run:

```
SELECT  Col
FROM    T
WHERE   Col = 1;
```

We get one row, where Col = 1, therefore logically if you run:

```
SELECT  Col
FROM    T
WHERE   NOT (Col = 1);
```

Or

```
SELECT  Col
FROM    T
WHERE   Col <> 1
```

You would expect the remaining 3 rows, but in both cases you will only get:

```
Col
----
2
3
```

This is because `NOT(NULL = 1)` and `NULL <> 1` are both `NULL`, so not true, so the 4th row isn't returned.

The way to get the result you are after is to use `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT  Col
FROM    T
EXCEPT
SELECT  Col
FROM    T
WHERE   Col = 1
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d225f4/2)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take NULLs into account, try this:

```
select * from table1 
where Not((row1 = 0 and row2 > 0) or  (row3 is null and row4 > 0))
or (row1 is null or row2 is null) and row4 is null
```